# Editing Boolean Function to Handle Lack of Value in Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, undefined

I have a function that's checking to see if a certain field in the API-revealed object has a value. The function returns a boolean. I am then styling some UI based on the result. The original function from the model looks like this:

```
public hasBillingCoverage(): boolean {
   if (this.coverage[0].payer) {
        return true;
   } else if (!this.coverage[0].payer || this.coverage[0].payer === undefined) {
       return false;
   }
}
```

And I am using that in the component like this:

```
private hasCoverageBillingInfo() {
    if (this.currentCustomer.hasFullName()) {
        if (this.currentCustomer.hasBillingCoverage()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log('Coverage info not provided...');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, currently I'm getting an error in the console, that reads:

> inline template:13:16 caused by: Cannot read property 'payer' of
>   undefined

That error points to this line in my component view:

```
<div class="page-content-header-item" [class.selected]="isSection('billing-and-coverage')" (click)="navigateTo('billing-and-coverage')"
[ngClass]="{'attention-needed': !hasCoverageBillingInfo()}">Billing and Coverage</div>
```

The above code in the view is designed to add some styling (the class "attention-needed') if the function "hasCoverageBillingInfo()" evaluates to false.

I thought I was already handling an undefined result, but apparently not. How can I edit this function so as to prevent the console error?

Comment: Assuming `coverage` is always an array, `return this.coverage[0] && this.coverage[0].payer`?

Comment: That did it. Many thanks, @jonrsharpe!